# .net core hosting - server has two .net core runtimes installed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Our app was originally built with .net core 1.x. We would like to upgrade to .net core 2.0.

I installed the hosting bundle from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle). But now I have the 1.0.0 Runtime and 2.0.5 runtime installed.

[image]

1. Do I need to uninstall the 1.0.0 runtime?
2. How can I tell which runtime my app will use?

Comment: It will always use the highest available version. You only need to uninstall the 1.x runtime if you don't have any other app that uses it. A .NET Core 2.X app cannot run on a 1.X runtime, though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for the answer. Do you know if the same is true for the "Windows Server Hosting" installation?

Comment: Following .NET and Microsoft conventions, yes, the same should hold true

Comment: The standard SDK and runtime installers contain *multiple* runtime versions to provide the necessary runtime for your app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that you should read the documentation for .NET Core. As Scott Hanselman (PM of the ASP.NET Core team) has pointed out, [multiple versions of the .NET Core runtime can be installed side by side without issue](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingDotnetCore20AndDotnetCore1xVersionedSDKsOnTheSameMachine.aspx)

As user [Camilo Terevinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141621/camilo-terevinto) pointed out in their comment, the highest version of the runtime will be used when your app is started.

Comment: You could also note that 2.X cannot run on 1.X, so if only a 1.X version is found the application won't run

Comment: Ah, found an answer directly from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server#a-need-for-side-by-side-of-net-versions-per-application-level

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has placed a limited life on the 1.0.0 runtime.  Since 2.0.0 introduced major changes, that break applications written in 1.0.0. For a more sustainable environment, you should remove the older runtime, then ensure the latest runtime and hosted core package are installed.  Those can be found on the document page.

To determine the runtime your application is utilizing, you can find that information within your project.  The assembly will include the information of which framework you're actually targeting against.